# Salesforce product development partner/ consulting partner/cloud alliance partner/all

Tags: partner

I have been a Salesforce developer for over 3 years. Lately i incorporated by business. Next i want to get my company enrolled into Salesforce partner program.

Over the internet, i have seen logos such as Cloud Alliance partner, Registered Partner, Consulting partner, Product development partner.

After reading the PDF guide for partner program, i think to become registered partner i need two Certifications - Sales/Service cloud and Developer. I already have the developer I certification, next i'll take admin and sales cloud. So the registered partner thing is figured out.

Next when i get to see cloud alliance partner and product development partner logos, i couldn't find much information about what they mean.

Essentially, my business targets both services and products. I'd highly appreciate if i could get the expert advice from the community to help me in my humble beginning.

My end goal is to partner with Salesforce, both as a services consultant as well as an app vendor.

Best Regards,

Sangram,

Comment: If you haven't already joined the ISV program, I'd recommend you visit there and request to join. The forums there would be a much more appropriate venue to ask these questions plus I think you'd get far better answers. This forum simply isn't intended nor is it suited for this type of question.